# Adding large resources with UpdateResource

Tags: delphi, winapi, resources

Nowhere in the Windows documentation do I see a reference to a size limit to the resources one can add using UpdateResource, but it seems I have stumbled upon one - and it's tiny!

I was developing a Windows Ribbon app and wanted to programmatically build and attach the resource. Linking the resource using a $R directive worked just dandy, but I kept getting memory junk when attaching the very same thing from code.

I have managed to reduce it to a simple example using a string resource:

```
  Handle := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(DestFileName), True);
  try
    AddResource(Handle, 'STRING', 'ManyXs', StrUtils.DupeString('X', 1000));
  finally
    EndUpdateResource(Handle, False);
  end;
```

And AddResource is defined as:

```
procedure TForm2.AddResource(Handle: NativeUInt; ResType, ResName, Value: string);
begin
  if not UpdateResource(Handle, PChar(ResType), PChar(ResName), 1033,
    PChar(Value), Value.Length * SizeOf(Char)) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Please ignore my hard-coded language for the moment.

When I inspect the resource subsequent to calling this, I see a thousand Xs. Fabulous.

I can change the resource to 1990 Xs and it's fine. The moment it goes to 1991, I get nonsense written to the DLL. The size of the resource is correctly indicated as 3982 (1991 * 2 because it's Unicode), but the contents is just a dump of stuff from memory.

I can view larger resources with my resource editor, and the IDE routinely inserts larger resources (Delphi forms, for example), so I'm definitely missing something.

I've tried the following, despite not thinking any of them would make a difference (they didn't):

1. Using just large memory buffers instead of strings
2. Using the Ansi version of the UpdateResource function
3. Many different resource types - what I really need to get working, is UIFILE
4. Looking for other functions in the API (I found none)
5. Combinations of 1, 2 and 3

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Inspired by the comments and Jolyon's answer, tried a few more things.

First, I tried in Delphi XE7 and XE5 as well (original was in XE6). I don't have XE2 installed anymore, so i cannot confirm what Sertak has said. I'll find out if someone else in my office still has it installed.

Second, here is the memory buffer version:

```
procedure TForm2.AddResource(Handle: NativeUInt; const ResType, ResName, Value: string);
var
  Buffer: Pointer;
  BuffLen: Integer;
begin
  BuffLen := Value.Length * SizeOf(Char);
  GetMem(Buffer, BuffLen);
  try
    StrPCopy(PChar(Buffer), Value);

    if not UpdateResource(Handle, PChar(ResType), PChar(ResName), 1033,
      Buffer, BuffLen) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    FreeMem(Buffer);
  end;
end;
```

I actually had a previous version of this code where I dumped the contents of that pointer into a file before the call to UpdateResource and the file saved correctly but the resource still saved junk. Then I did this version, which doesn't involve strings at all:

```
procedure TForm2.AddResource(Handle: NativeUInt; const ResType, ResName: string; 
  C: AnsiChar; Len: Integer );
var
  Buffer: Pointer;
  BuffLen: Integer;
begin
  BuffLen := Len;
  GetMem(Buffer, BuffLen);
  try
    FillMemory(Buffer, Len, Byte(C));

    if not UpdateResource(Handle, PChar(ResType), PChar(ResName), 1033,
      Buffer, BuffLen) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    FreeMem(Buffer);
  end;
end;
```

With this version I still have the same problem when I use 3882 Xs. Of course, I'm now using single-byte characters, that's why it's double. But I have the exact same issue.

I did notice a difference between the versions in the output of TDUMP though. For versions 1 (strings) and 2 (string copied to buffer), my resource size is suddenly indicated as FFFFFF90 when I use 1991 characters. With version 3 (no strings), the size is the actual hex value of whatever size I used.

Comment: Bearing in mind I know very little of Delphi, is `string` a "narrow" string? The documentation for [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that `lpData` must not point to ANSI data, it _must_ be Unicode. So perhaps using `WideString` instead may be an idea? Looking [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Text) suggests that `String` defaults to be an `AnsiString`.

Comment: @icabod In modern Delphi `string` is UTF-16 `UnicodeString`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There's a _modern_ Delphi!?!

Comment: @icabod There is. Sounds like you are behind the times. Also a big mistake to use ancient delphi basics site. Delphi is well-documented, documentation is online. Keep up please!  ;-)

Comment: Cannot duplicate, tested with XE2 with 50000 dupes.

Comment: This might be a wild gues but I wpuld recomend you chech the created file using PE Explorer to see how diferent file sections (.text, .data, .rcData, .resource) are arranged. While resource section of the executable file is usually placed at the end of the file I have seen files where this wasn't ture. I have even seen files with multiple resource section in them.  Anywhay if resource section is not positioned last then it is posible that it is being overwritten by some other section. You can download free trial of PE Explorer from: http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm

Comment: Can you verify the *weird* resource size with Anders Melander's [Resorce Editor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/)? It explicitly displays the size of the resource.

Comment: So would I be correct if I conclude that the fault was on your resource viewer/editor?

Comment: @Sertac - No, you can conclude that I was on conference for two days and then it was weekend ;) I downloaded the resource editor you suggested (very nice btw); it gives me the resource as expected if I use a small size, but "Failed to load resource module. System Error. Code 1812. The specified image file did not contain a resource section." if I attach a larger resource. The message isn't correct though, as I can see the resource with both TDUMP and my own code that will load the resource. It is found, but contains nonsense. And as I mentioned in my update, tdump reports a very strange size.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I got hold of an XE3 installation and got the exact same problem. Also, since this is a Windows API call, I don't understand why the Delphi version should make a difference. Did you take a copy of my function or write your own? Perhaps there is a problem in what I do that you didn't have in your code.

Comment: @Cobus - i agree that version should not matter regarding the code. But now I wonder if the executable that is modified matters, in my case it was a console application also produced by XE2. I used your code AFAIR.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are getting "junk" data but data of the right *size* leads me to suspect the **PChar()** casting of the string value yielding an incorrect address.  This normally should not be a problem, but I wonder if the issue is some strange behaviour as the result of passing the result of a function directly into a parameter of a method ?  A behaviour which for some strange reason is only triggered when the string involved reaches a certain size, perhaps indicating some edge-case optimization behaviour.

This might also explain difficulties in reproducing the problem if it is some combination of optimization (and/or other compiler settings) in some specific version of Delphi.

I would suggest to try eliminating this possibility by creating your new resource string in an explicit variable and passing that to the **AddResource()** method.  I would also suggest that you be explicit in your parameter semantics and since the string involved is not modified, nor intended to be modified, in the **AddResource()** method, declare it as a formally **const** parameter.

You do mention having tried an alternative approach using "memory buffers".  If the above suggestions do not resolve the problem, perhaps it would be helpful to post a minimal example that reproduces the problem using those, to eliminate any possible influence on things by the rather more exotic "string" type.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment. Certainly I know of no such bug. We'd have noticed by now.

Comment: You'd be surprised how long bugs can go unnoticed for.   I can think of at least two in Delphi that went for a very long time before cropping up in the wild (and longer before being fixed).   I did also suggestion to further simplify,.   Perhaps consider this as offsetting all those comments which should be answers  :) .  (fwiw I did hesitate to post it as an answer,  but comments aren't big enough)